# Why does removal of async/await cause conversion error for Task<T> to Task<object>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following generic and non-generic methods:

```cs
public async Task<T> LoadAsync(Guid id)
{
    return await _someService.SomeMethodAsync(id);
}

async Task<object> LoadObjectAsync(Guid id) => await LoadAsync(id);
```

Trying to follow the [advice from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), I thought I'd make the code more efficient by removing the async/await from the `LoadObjectAsync` method as it is a passthrough. However, when I change the signature to:

```cs
Task<object> LoadObjectAsync(Guid id) => LoadAsync(id);
```

I get an error saying I cannot implicitly convert from `Task<T>` to `Task<object>`. What I'd like to know is how the async await avoids this conversion issue? I know that generic variance prohibits the conversion of the `Task<>` but why does this not apply to the async/await version?

Comment: They are both generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Trying to follow the advice from Stephen Cleary

The advice in that article is "leave the `async`/`await` in there unless you need to remove it". In this case, the method *looks* like a passthrough but is actually doing an implicit cast.

> What I'd like to know is why the async await avoids this conversion issue?

With `async` and `await`, the code is casting `T` to `object`, which is always allowed.

Without `async` and `await`, the code is casting `Task<T>` to `Task<object>`, which is not allowed. This is because classes cannot support [generic variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), and there is no `ITask<T>` type.